# does hashing suffice encryption

Tags: security, web-applications, salt

does using hash functions and algorithims suffice the need to encrypt the data, while communicating with the server

I am applying salt mechanism in my project and I will be concatenating the salt with the entered password, and then hash them all.

do I still need to encrypt the result?

Answer (score 0):

The usual workflow for a website to transmit user passwords looks like this:

1. The client sends the password *plaintext* to the server.
2. The transmission is done with an *encrypted connection* (HTTPS/SSL), to prevent a ManInTheMiddle attack.
3. The server calculates a *hash* of the plaintext password, and this hash is then stored in the database. It is not necessary to encrypt the hash any further.

Make sure you use a random unique salt for each password, and a slow hash function with a cost factor for hashing passwords. Good algorithms are BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

**Storing passwords**

To store user passwords securely, you need 3 things:

1. Do not store the plain password, store a **hash** instead

   The hash makes it extremely difficult to recuperate the password even if an attacker manages to capture the entire database
2. To prevent the use of rainbow tables, you need a **salt**

   The salt is stored in the clear (can be along with the hash) and is random, one for every user and you can easily chose a few one whenever the user changes their password.
3. You need a **SLOW** hash, not a fast hash

   What are fast hashes: MD5 (consider it broken), SHA-1, SHA-2, ... are unsuitable as the attacker can perform them too fast and use dictionary attacks to try common passwords and find that way up to 95% of you user's passwords in mere hours on modern rigs.

   How slow does it need to be ? As slow as you can afford.

And there's a rule 0: **Do not invent crypto yourself**, you will make serious mistakes before you know it.

**Other privacy sensitive info**

You're most probably also storing other sensitive information of your visitors in addition to the passwords (email addresses, IP addresses, names, postal address, ...), CC numbers (you better not go there), ...

You need to protect that as well and using hashes isn't the way to do that in most cases. Some of these have requirements and regulations of their own (e.g. Credit Card data is regulated by the issuers who'll force you to be compliant with PCI-DSS).

In essence you need to do a risk analysis and manage that risk by either accepting it ("so be it"), transferring it ("get insurance"), avoid it ("we're not storing that"), or mitigating it ("we're going to improve our way of working").

**encryption**

Why the media will make you believe there's a "magic" solution in that incomprehensible "encryption" thing, in reality it needs to be done right and in the right conditions to have any meaning at all.

E.g. If you encrypt the entire disk of a server: it will not protect you from an attacker abusing your server scripts and getting to the database (as the database engine and webserver scripts have access to the decrypted disk already)

So, you really need to go back to the risk analysis and chose the measures there instead of getting ahead of yourself and suggesting encryption as a tool that's unlikely to help you for your biggest risks.